# How do I Iterate through a list and check if two objects are equal

Tags: c#, list

Looking for a more compressed version to check if two classes are equal in a list.

```
private bool foo()
{
    if (bar.Count <= 0) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < bar.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < bar.Count; k++)
        {
            if (i != k)
            {
                if (bar[i].Equals(bar[k])) return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The first optimization is not to always start the inner loop at `0`, instead do `for (int k = i+1; k < bar.Count; k++)` which also means you don't need this check `if (i != k)`

Comment: Don't ask for short code, ask for readable and concise code.

Comment: @Aomine: Thanks for the tip will use in the future new to programing so every tip helps! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the linq Distinct() method:

```
return bar.Count > bar.Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i wanted first time using Linq

Comment: Or do it yourself the way `Distinct` does, except returning on the first match: `var set = new HashSet<BarType>(); for(int i=0;i<bar.Count;++i) if (!set.Add(bar[i])) return true; return false;` Not as compact, but will out perform `Distinct` so long as the first match isn't the last item (though most certainly not noticeable on small lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` queries for finding duplicates in your list, I hope the List object is implementing `IComparable` interface. to find out duplicated you can use following code.

```
var duplicates = bar.GroupBy(b => b)
.SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have two `List<String` , here's a sample code that might save your day :)

```
 private List<string> checkifMatch(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2)
{
    List<string> matches= new List<string>();

    matches.AddRange(lst1.Except(lst2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    matches.AddRange(lst2.Except(lst1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so its always interesting testing answers for performance (just for fun).

So i compared your version with the inner loop modification as suggested by  Aominè with Dave M's version

**Exmaple**

```
if (Input.Count <= 0) return false;

for (var i = 0; i < Input.Count; i++)
   for (var k = i; k < Input.Count; k++)    
         if (i != k && Input[i].Equals(Input[k])) return true;

return false;
```

**Results**

```
Test Framework : .NET Framework 4.7.1

Scale : 100
Name            |      Time |     Delta |  Deviation |  Cycles
--------------------------------------------------------------
Distinct        |  0.019 ms |  0.000 ms |       0.06 |  58,785
Yours with mod  |  0.036 ms |  0.001 ms |       0.11 |  84,808


Scale : 1000
Name            |      Time |     Delta |  Deviation |     Cycles
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Distinct        |  0.074 ms |  0.023 ms |       0.02 |    240,076
Yours with mod  |  1.638 ms |  0.163 ms |       0.09 |  5,560,397


Scale : 10000
Name            |        Time |     Delta |  Deviation |       Cycles
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Distinct        |    0.708 ms |  0.017 ms |       0.05 |    2,400,189
Yours with mod  |  158.829 ms |  0.000 ms |       8.08 |  540,243,590
```

**Summary** : Although one-liners and Linq can make your printable character OCD feel good, sometimes they just don't scale well and are the opposite of performant. I think this one speaks for itself distinct wins hands down.

As you can see yours scales exponentially, its basically because distinct internally uses a set and iterates the list once with time complexity of O(n)

Comment: Thanks for running these test if you don't mind could u point me in the right detection  on how i would do this myself ? still learning :)

Comment: @Hammertime  I wrote my own benchmark framework today so just playing with it on the questions tonight. however you can use this awesome library https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet